# How to merge raster scenes while maintaining small file size?

Tags: qgis, gdal-merge

I have 4 scenes of raster images that I need to merge. Average size of the scenes is only 60 MB, but the merged scene ended up at 6 GB in file size. Does anyone know why this happened?

Comment: Clarify: How did you merge them (what tool/algorithm)? What format were the source files in? What is the output format? How many bands/channels do the images have (RGB or more)?

Comment: Are your scenes far apart each other? Empty pixels between the scenes take as much disk space as those which contain data if you do not use compression. Also if you use your GeoTIFFs only with QGIS and GDAL the "Sparse files" option may be good for you http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html. Consider also using gdalbuildvrt http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html instead of writing scenes into a physical file.

Comment: I used GDAL raster merge tool. The original format of the scenes are geoTIFF with single gray band. The scenes are adjacent to one another, no spaces between them.

Comment: Add gdalinfo about one source image and about the 6 GB result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried adding compression to the creation options, e.g.

```
gdal_merge.py input1.tif input2.tif -o output.tif -co 'COMPRESS=LZW'
```

Comment: From my similar question (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258187/gdal-merged-files-take-more-space), also try adding `-co PREDICTOR=2` and `-co TILED=YES`

Answer (score 3):

If you have **RGB Files** you can use JPEG Compression + YCBCR.
Add the following to your gdal_merge command:

```
-co COMPRESS=JPEG -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR
```

If you have **RGBA** files (RGB + alpha channel) leave out the PHOTOMETRIC part

```
-co COMPRESS=JPEG
```

if you don't have RGB images, you can use LZW Compression  as suggested by [dmci](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/242031/87998). ( + Use all CPUs for compression). Note: This has much worse performance than JPG Compression.

```
-co COMPRESS=LZW -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS
```

---

**Additional information**

For better view performance, use inner tiling, for faster merging add some I/O Cache.

Get some information regarding [gdal_merge here](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html) and [Geotiff format here](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html)

---

The command that I usually use is this one:

```
gdal_merge.py \
-of GTiff -ot Byte -o outfile.tif \
-co TILED=YES \
-co BLOCKXSIZE=512 \
-co BLOCKYSIZE=512 \
-co COMPRESS=JPEG \
-co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR \
--config GDAL_CACHEMAX 512 \
file1 file2 file3
```

At the End I use [gdaladdo](http://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html) to add overviews for best performance!