# gdal_merge'd files take more space

Tags: gdal, gdal-merge

I have two 3.6 MB GeoTIFF compressed with LZW. When I merge them with:

```
gdal_merge.py *.tif -o ~/out.tif  -co COMPRESS=LZW -co BIGTIFF=YES
```

The files is 10x larger at 31 MB.

Is there some reason the filesize would increase when merging? They are a continuous region (all touching each other), in EPSG 3413 projection.

This question was asked here ([How to merge raster scenes while maintaining small file size?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242028/how-to-merge-raster-scenes-while-maintaining-small-file-size?rq=1)) but not answered. That OP selected the "use compression" answer, but my compressed file is *larger*. I'm posting `gdalinfo` for one input file (first) and the final file (below).

**NOTE** Oddly, when I do this for >2 files, or the whole folder which is 800 MB, it is 8.4 GB uncompress, and **LARGER**, or 11 GB with LZW compression.

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: gimpdem0_0_v1.1.tif
Size is 8310, 15000
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",70],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-45],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",1],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",1],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (-640000.000000000000000,-2905550.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (30.000000000000000,-30.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -640000.000,-2905550.000) ( 57d25'19.50"W, 63d 1'28.29"N)
Lower Left  ( -640000.000,-3355550.000) ( 55d47'53.80"W, 59d11'57.96"N)
Upper Right ( -390700.000,-2905550.000) ( 52d39'30.45"W, 63d24'19.24"N)
Lower Right ( -390700.000,-3355550.000) ( 51d38'28.63"W, 59d31'30.22"N)
Center      ( -515350.000,-3130550.000) ( 54d20'53.46"W, 61d18'11.32"N)
Band 1 Block=8310x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

And the merged file:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /Users/kdm/Desktop/20171011-204436.tif
Size is 8310, 30000
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",70],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-45],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",1],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",1],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (-640000.000000000000000,-2455550.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (30.000000000000000,-30.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -640000.000,-2455550.000) ( 59d36'29.72"W, 66d52'51.74"N)
Lower Left  ( -640000.000,-3355550.000) ( 55d47'53.80"W, 59d11'57.96"N)
Upper Right ( -390700.000,-2455550.000) ( 54d 2'25.84"W, 67d20' 7.02"N)
Lower Right ( -390700.000,-3355550.000) ( 51d38'28.63"W, 59d31'30.22"N)
Center      ( -515350.000,-2905550.000) ( 55d 3'28.16"W, 63d14'13.92"N)
Band 1 Block=8310x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Comment: I am suprised to see COMPRESS=LZW is larger file than without. In your last output it doesn't show it in Image Structure Metadata:`

Comment: Correct. I'm working with the smaller, uncompressed file.

Comment: The input images are compressed with LZW and the output merged TIFF is not. That is the root cause of why the output file is so large. The next question is why is the `gdal_merge` command not creating a compressed TIFF. I would suggest completely removing (or renaming) the output file and trying the command again. If it continues then try it without the `BIGTIFF` creation option (after deleting/renaming the existing file). If this continues to be a problem try just two of the GIMP tiles and run `gdalinfo` to see if you can get LZW compression working...

Comment: Clarified and edited. 1) With 2 files, the compressed goes from 2*3.6 MB to 36 MB. Uncompressed goes from 2*3.6 MB to 476 MB. Compression = good. But why 10x and not 2x the size? But, when doing all files, it goes from 800 MB to 8.4 GB (uncompressed) and 800 MB to 11 GB (**larger**) when compressed.

Comment: Try if file shrinks better if you add `-co PREDICTOR=2` or `-co TILED=YES`, or both.

Comment: Wow. The two 3.6 MB files went from 36 MB -> 4.5 MB. I'm now trying with the full 800 MB folder (that turned to 11 GB when merged).

Comment: Final size is 700 MB. And it is **much** faster. Thank you for suggesting these `-co` flags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To put the comments into an answer:

It looks like the processing was doing a bad job at predicting the optimal compression? Coupled with no tiling there was really inefficient storage.

The solution was to use the [geotiff creation options](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html) `PREDICTOR=2` & `TILED=YES`.

The final command to call is then

```
gdal_merge.py *.tif -o ~/out.tif  \
  -co COMPRESS=LZW -co BIGTIFF=YES -co PREDICTOR=2 -co TILED=YES
```

**EDIT**

An explanation about what happens, taken from http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/corion-lzw.htm

> The TIFF predictor algorithm
>
> The idea  is to  make use  of the  fact that many continuous tone
>   images rarely  vary much  in pixel  value from  one pixel  to the
>   next.   In such  images,  if  we  replace  the  pixel  values  by
>   differences between  consecutive pixels,  many of the differences
>   should be  0, plus  or minus  1, and  so on.   This  reduces  the
>   apparent information  content, and  thus allows LZW to encode the data
>   more compactly.